# Is it possible to submit data to separate tables using the same form?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, axios, vuex

Hi I am curious if it is possible to submit data to separate tables using the same form... Currently I have a `user_id` column residing on my tasks table and a `status` column on my engagements table. Now perhaps there is a better way to do it but when A task is complete the `user_id` needs to be updated and the `status` of the engagement needs to be updated. For user experience reasons I would like for these to be updated at the same time.

Now Im using vue.js with vuex and the data is submitted with axios to my laravel backend, so the component to update the task looks like this

```
   <b-modal v-model="modalShow" id="myQuestion" ref="myQuestion" hide-footer title="Update Engagement">
            <form @submit.prevent="updateThisTask">
            <div>
              <div class="input-group my-3">
              <div class="input-group-prepend">
                <label class="input-group-text font-weight-bold bg-primary text-light" for="option">Assign To</label>
              </div>
              <select class="custom-select" id="client_id" v-model="task.user_id">
                <option v-for="user in users" :key="user.id" :value="user.id">
                  {{ user.name }}
                </option>
              </select>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="d-flex">
              <b-btn class="mt-3" variant="secondary" @click="modalShow = false">Cancel</b-btn>
              <b-btn class="mt-3 ml-auto" variant="outline-primary" @click="updateThisTask(task.id)">Confirm</b-btn>
            </div>
            </form>
        </b-modal>
```

When the modal pops up I want them to have the option to update the assigned to user(which at this point im already doing), and I want the option to assign the status. When I run the method `updateThisTask`, is there a way I can separate the data out at that point before it is submitted?

here is the method in the script section, right now it is only updating the user_id

```
methods: {
    ...mapActions(['updateTask']),

    updateThisTask(id) {
      if(!this.task.user_id) {
        return
      } else {
        this.updateTask({
          id: this.task.id,
          user_id: this.task.user_id
        }) 
      }  
    }
  },
```

If I am way off base please let me know.

Thanks

Comment: Why separate the data out before it's submitted vs handle putting the data in whatever tables you want from the controller you're submitting to?

Comment: @wheelmaker, makes sense. Just trying to wrap my head around it. Backend would probably be the better option just looking for ideas.

Comment: yeah I would either handle that in the controller or set up an observer for your tasks model that automatically triggers the update

Answer (score 0):

From the description of the problem, it seems you want send one single action to `vuex` in order to update two different tables on your back-end, and want the changes to be updated to user at the same time.

If that's the case, you can achieve that with an `action` which `POST` to your API to both tables, and perform two successive `commit` after API calls are completed:

```js
export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    tasks: [...],
    engagements: [...],
  },
  mutations: {
    updateTask: (state, { taskId, userId }) => {
      // update state.tasks[taskId] however you want here
    },
    updateEngagement: (state, { userId }) => {
      // update state.engagements[userId] however you want here
    },
  },
  actions: {
    async updateTask({ commit }, { taskId, userId }) {
      const prefix = 'http://localhost/';
      try {
        // make API calls here
        const update1 = await axios.post(`${prefix}tasks/complete`, { taskId, userId });
        const update2 = await axios.post(`${prefix}/engagements/update`, { userId });

        // changes made by both commits will appear to user at the same time
        // since commit() is synchronous
        commit('updateTask', { taskId, userId });
        commit('updateEngagement', { userId });
      } catch (e) {
        console.log(`error occurred: ${JSON.stringify(e)}`);
      }
    },
  },
});
```